# Invoking thread for each item in list simultaneously and returning value in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I made a wrapper for an API that I am using, basically what I'm doing is sending in a list of `Series` objects and for each item in the list, a thread ("worker"?) starts and fetches information for their respective series.

The API that I'm using doesn't support fetching several series using one request, which would simplify this by a large margin, therefore I run threads for each item in the list.

I'm mostly concerned about the thread part, but I'll provide all the other parts as well.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/series", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Response> fetchSeveralSeries(@RequestBody List<Series> list) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<Callable<Response>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        callableList.add(new performRequest(list.get(i).getSeries()));
    }

    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(list.size());
    List<Future<Response>> futureObjects = service.invokeAll(callableList);
    List<Response> series = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Future<Response> obj : futureObjects) {
        series.add(obj.get());
    }

    return series;
}
```

Callable class used. (temporarily in my Spring boot controller class, as my entire implementation is in the controller atm.)

```
private class performRequest implements Callable<Response> {
    private int seriesId;

    private performRequest(int seriesId) {
        this.seriesId = seriesId;
    }

    @Override
    public Response call() throws UnirestException {
        return request.send(new Url(seriesId).toString());
    }
}
```

About the request made by each thread, I have a `Url` class which constructs the Url for the request and a `Request` class which sends the request to the external API.

`Request` class which sends the request to external API. The `Response` object is a "GSON Object".

```
@Service
public class Request {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Request.class);

    public Response send(String url) throws UnirestException {
        logger.info("sending GET");
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> json = Unirest.get(url).asJson();
        String body = json.getBody().toString();
        return new Gson().fromJson(body, Response.class);
    }

}
```

`Url` class which constructs the URL.

```
@Data
public class Url {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
    private static final String API_KEY = System.getenv("API_KEY");

    private Integer id;
    private Integer season;
    private Integer episode;
    private String searchQuery; // should turn spaces into %20

    public Url(String searchQuery) {
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    public Url(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Url(Integer id, Integer season) {
        this.id = id;
        this.season = season;
    }

    public Url(Integer id, Integer season, Integer episode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.season = season;
        this.episode = episode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.searchQuery != null ?
                String.format("%s/search/tv?api_key=%s&language=en-US&query=%s", BASE_URL, API_KEY, this.searchQuery) : this.episode != null ?
                String.format("%s/tv/%s/season/%s/episode/%s?api_key=%s&language=en-US", BASE_URL, this.id, this.season, this.episode, API_KEY) : this.season != null ?
                String.format("%s/tv/%s/season/%s?api_key=%s&language=en-US", BASE_URL, this.id, this.season, API_KEY) :
                String.format("%s/tv/%s?api_key=%s&language=en-US", BASE_URL, this.id, API_KEY);
    }

}
```

An example `POST` request body would be something like below:

```
[
    {
        "series": 37680
    },
    {
        "series": 53123
    },
    {
        "series": 12345
    },
    {
        "series": 29182
    }
]
```

Could my code be improved somehow? Would it be possible to decrease response time? Is it "thread-safe"?
  Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following point:

1. For `Request.send()` is thread safe as it does not used any sharing resource of `Request` class.
2. As per provided code single(singleton) object will be created as per default spring configuration.
3. You must shutdown *ExecutorService* once no more thread need to be add.